# How to check if a google account is phone verified?

Tags: google-signin

I'm adding Google login and Facebook login to my site.
With Facebook api, I can get a user field called "verified" that shows whether the user is phone verified.
Is there a way that I can get this info from Google API?

Comment: refer the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/)

Comment: @krishnan I have read the doc and searched many times before asking this question.

Comment: There are separate Google API for different platform like Android , iOS and Web.you want to  select the API for your platform.(for example GoogleApiClient is used for android)

Comment: @krishnan Your text is not related to my question. Maybe you don't understand my question. Please take a look at what is "verified" mean in Facebook api.